# Arabic Text with URL converting to?

Tags: java, encoding

I have an arabic text which looks like this

```
جمعية الفجيرة الخيرية
للتبرع:
http://myaddress/Filename.jpg
```

but when I receive it on my mobile it becomes like this

```
????? ??????? ???????
??????:
http://myaddress/Filename.jpg
```

I am sending the message as UTF-16 format and it works if the text is only Arabic or Arabic + English but if I add the URL in the text it shows ? as characters.

Comment: There is no support for UTF8 in SMS. You can use UTF-16 (technically SMS must be in UCS-2, but for your purpose the two are the same)

Comment: But .net environment is by default UTF-16 and by using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString() code I get UTF-16 based string.

Comment: *I am sending the message as UTF-8* You can't do it. `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString() ` There is a UTF8 word in it. You can't do it :-)

Comment: I edited my question. I just came to know the app is in Java and the encoding is UTF-16